# Video auto play I want when user click on play button the video play

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

**Video auto play I want when user click on play button the video play.**

```
VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    Uri uri=Uri.parse(selectedItem.getTrailerLink());
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty simple: don't call `start()` right away.

Move that to the onClick method for the button, and you're good to go